# Laravel view suddenly stop updating changes made to the code

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am working on a project with Laravel. Getting to a point, I restarted my system, turning my development back on, every change I make to Laravel view does not effect. Even after save and refresh. Have restarted the server and system multiple times, cleared all browser data. The problem Still persist. Any help please.

Comment: did you try `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: View:clear worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to clear your view cache:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

View caching is done because blade compiling each time is a waste of time.

Comment: Voalah! Worked like a charm. Thank you. Am new to Laravel.